# checked radio button value from datalist?

Tags: asp.net

I want to put some questions with a data list view with multiple choice radio button so how to get each question answer or checked radio button value from list?

Comment: THere are already so many questions in this topic in SO. Have you researched them before posting and if so what is the difference in your question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
            {
                // Checking the item is a data item
                if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    var rdbList = item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1") as RadioButtonList;
                    // Get the selected value
                    string selected = rdbList.SelectedValue;
                }
            }
        }
```

try this and let me know